# how to append my extjs datepicker and time fields values together

Tags: extjs

```
{
                title: 'End Date',
                margin: '0 20 0 0',
                items:{
                    xtype: 'datepicker',
                    itemId: 'endDate',
                    value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                    showToday: false,
                    handler: function(picker, date) {
                        var timeIntervalPanel = this.up('button#timeIntervalPanel');
                        var startDate = timeIntervalPanel.startDate;
                        timeIntervalPanel.setDates(startDate, date);
                }
                }
            }]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [
                    {
                        margin: '0 20 0 0',
                        items:{
                        xtype: 'timefield',
                        name: 'startHourCombo',
                        id: 'startTime',
                        maxWidth: 100,
                        columnWidth: 0.2,
                        minValue: '12:00 AM',
                        maxValue: '11:00 PM',
                        increment: 60,
                        anchor: '100%',
                        value: '12:00 AM'

                        }
                }
```

Comment: Do you want to show time at the side of date field? have a look at format config of datefield. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-format.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

[image]

Then the code is

```
 {
                     xtype : 'container',
                     layout : 'hbox',
                     defaults :{
                        margin :'10 10 10 10' 
                     },
                     items :[
                             {
                                 xtype: 'datefield',                                    
                                 fieldLabel: 'Date',

                             },
                             {
                                 xtype: 'timefield',
                                 name: 'startHourCombo',
                                 id: 'startTime',
                                 maxWidth: 100,
                                 columnWidth: 0.2,
                                 minValue: '12:00 AM',
                                 maxValue: '11:00 PM',
                                 increment: 60,
                                 anchor: '100%',
                                 value: '12:00 AM'
                             }
                             ]
                 }
```

Comment: i want to append the selected values from datefield and time field together and display

Comment: That would be very involved and would involve you writing a new datepicker.  You'll probably need to extend the datepicker component and modify it to have a new picker.